# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS dual monitor failure

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

Currently, my two monitors are connected with HDMI and VGA. They both work during login, and I can see both screens showing the ubuntu magenta color.

Once I log in, only one monitor displays the screen while the other loses its signal. When I try to change the display setting to mirror, the screen gets mirrored for a brief second and glitches out. Then, it forces the display back into a single display mode. When I choose to join displays, the screen flickers and the main screen turns black, only showing the mouse cursor and the other screen just doesn't work (the mouse can't even enter that monitor). The only way out of that weird glitch is forcefully rebooting. No shortcut keys that I know worked.

Weirdly, though, when I choose to do single displays for either monitor, they work flawlessly. So I'm guessing it's not a hardware problem.

I'm so confused because this setup worked fine up until I briefly changed the display to a single monitor for a bit and tried to revert back to the original setup.

Thank you so much in advance.